# Date filter in Django model results unexpected behavior

Tags: python, django

It seems to be easy but it creates confusion for me. My code is

```
today = datetime.datetime.now()
StatusObj = Status.objects.filter(taskPeople__people__email = useremail,dateCreated__year = today.year, dateCreated__month = today.month, dateCreated__day = today.day)
```

it is expected that it will filter the query whose date is today. But it doesn't filter instead it filter one day back query.
when I do.

```
today.day
>> 20
Status.objects.filter(taskPeople__people__email = useremail,dateCreated__year = today.year, dateCreated__month = today.month, dateCreated__day = today.day)[0].dateCreated.day
>>19
```

Comment: What is the default timezone you are using in your application ?

Comment: TIME_ZONE ='Asia/Calcutta'

Comment: So, the thing is, The backend database stores the value in UTC ( IST - 5:30) and django is timezone aware, and making that conversion for you. Hence the issue.

Comment: Can you please guide me what to do?

Comment: First thing I would do is, check to see if that indeed is the issue (In the database, check if dateCreated is stored as 19th ) - Django is smart enough to do the rest of conversion for you.

Comment: I have both date created 19th as-well as 20

Comment: In my database  i have 2015-01-20 00:01:59.558969+05:30 and   2015-01-19 00:01:17.141224+05:30

Answer (score 1):

You should use `django.utils.timezone.now` instead of `datetime.datetime.now`.

```
from django.utils import timezone
today = timezone.now()
...
```

Read the question #3 in the [troubleshooting](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/i18n/timezones/#troubleshooting) section of the timezones docs.

Comment: Did as above mentioned but getting same result.

Comment: Have you installed `pytz`? Is the timezone on your machine match the timezone in `settings.py`?

Comment: i have installed pytz. I use this application on many computer